# Why does GitHub need me to rebase a Merge Request when nothing has changed in the MR

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

When working with GitHub, I do not understand if I make a merge request that three days later when I go to approve the MR it says I need to rebase the MR? Can anyone explain this its driving me crazy. I am new to GitHub so please anything would be much helpfull, thank you.

Comment: Probably there is a rule set up on the repo that asks for MRs to only be accepted if they are from the tip of the target branch (forcing a rebase). But it's not a git problem. It's a (configurable) github thing

Comment: There was some changes in the branch your PR is targeting, so you have to rebase to take them into account. This is indeed a PR strategy option in GitHub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git—and GitHub—does not necessarily need this.  The things that need it are humans, and/or rules imposed by humans.  The following is long but I suggest it is worth reading.

#### Long: what rebase is about

To use Git and GitHub effectively, you should know the following:

- Git does not have pull requests or merge requests.  These are add-ons, provided by various hosting sites (GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, and others).
- GitHub call their add-ons *pull requests;* it's GitLab that call theirs *merge requests*.

These are both relatively minor, but because Git terminology is already horribly confusing, it's best to be as clear as possible.

Regardless of what they call them and how they implement them internally and externally—these also differ from hosting site to hosting site—these do all build on some fundamental Git technologies.  Mastering these will help.  Here's what to know:

- Git is built around *commits*.  The commit is the [*raison d'être*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre) for Git.  Nothing else really matters except insofar as it acts in service to commits.
- Every commit has a unique number, usually expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), that looks like a big ugly string of letters and digits.  In an important way, that number *is* the commit, which is why it's required to be unique.  Two Gits, when talking to each other, will just exchange the raw numbers to see if they both have the commit.  If not, one Git may have to send the commit to the other Git.  (Git repositories "like to" add new commits to themselves, and "dislike" ever forgetting any commit.<sup>1</sup>)  We call these numbers *hash IDs*.
- Every commit contains two things:

  - Each commit has a snapshot of all of the files of some project.  The internal storage format here is complicated, and not really relevant, but it's worth knowing that (1) it acts as a snapshot and (2) all the files in it are *de-duplicated* against all the copies that exist in any other commit, so the fact that most commits mostly contain the same files as most other commits doesn't bloat up the repository too much.
  - Each commit has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it and when, for instance.  The metadata include your name and email address (from `user.name` and `user.email` settings) and any log message you put in.  And—crucial from Git's point of view—each commit contains the raw commit hash ID(s) of some set of earlier commit(s).
- All parts of any commit, once created, are read-only.  One reason for this is that the hash ID of a commit is just a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of the commit.<sup>2</sup>  If you take a commit—or any internal object—out of the Git database, make some changes, and write the result back in, you just get a new object with a different hash ID.  The original object remains.

This last bit makes Git repositories generally append-only (which explains the anthropomorphized "liking" of adding new commits).  It *is* possible to take some existing commits that are not "good enough" and copy them to new-and-improved commits, *and* to stop using the old commits.  If *every* Git repository does so, the old commits can eventually "fall away".<sup>3</sup>  **This is what `git rebase` is about.**

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers—they hate that!

<sup>2</sup>This implies that each commit must be unique.  The stored hash ID of a previous commit, plus the time-stamps, help out here, for instance.  It also means that Git must eventually fail: the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that any hashing scheme will eventually have a collision.  The *size* of the hash ID determines *how quickly* Git might fail.  It's been engineered to make it take many decades before this occurs.  Malicious hacking of SHA-1 can lead to earlier failure, though, and the size of repositories is growing in general, both of which are causing Git to move from SHA-1 to SHA-256 eventually.

<sup>3</sup>The details are complicated and we won't cover them here.

---

#### Working in a Git repository

When humans do work in a Git repository, the process generally goes like this:

1. Clone some existing repository if needed, or, update if needed, then use existing clone.
2. Do some work.  Make new commits, because Git is all about *commits*.
3. Test and rework as needed.
4. Announce readiness.
5. Go through any review process; this may send one back to step 2 or 3.
6. Incorporate the work.

If only one person is doing any work at any time, and no reworking or cycling-through-steps occurs, this process is pretty straightforward.  The only squirrelly parts happen at steps 1 and 6.  If we ignore those, we see a nice, simple process that looks like this.  Here, I'll draw commits using single uppercase letters to stand in for their hash IDs:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
```

Right now, the commit whose hash ID is `H` is the *latest* commit on the `main` or `master` branch.  Git itself doesn't care at all about branch names: it just uses them to *find* commits.  Specifically, a branch name holds the hash ID of *one* commit, and that one commit *is* the latest commit that we—or Git—will call "part of the branch".

Since each commit holds the hash ID of an earlier commit—or sometimes two earlier commits; we'll see this in a moment—commit `H` contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`, hence the backwards arrow in the drawing above.

Commit `H` also contains a full snapshot of every file.  These are the files we get to work on / with, when we run `git checkout main`.  Note that the files we work on / with go in our *working tree*.  They are *copied out of* the commit: in the commit, they're in some special weird Git-only format, compressed and de-duplicated, not usable by most of the software on the computer.

Git *found* commit `H` using the hash ID stored in the *name* `main`.  That's how `git checkout main` (or `git switch main`, in Git 2.23 or later) got all the files out of it.  And, that's how `git log` shows you information *about* commit `H`: it uses the name `main` to look up the hash ID, and then uses the hash ID to look up the internal commit in a big database-of-all-Git-commits-and-other-supporting-objects.

Since commit `H` stores commit `G`'s hash ID, Git can use that to fish commit `G`'s files out too, and can *compare* the snapshot in `G` to that in `H`.  By doing that, Git can show us what files, if any, *changed*, and what changes were made, even though `H` is just a snapshot.

Of course, commit `G` is a full commit, with a previous commit hash ID `F`, so Git can load both commits `F` and `G` and use that to show what changed in commit `G`.  The `git log` command can also show the log message *for* commit `G`, having found the hash ID from commit `H`.

And of course, commit `F` is a full commit, so Git can go on doing this.  It can keep it up all the way back to the very first commit ever.  *That* commit is special in one way: it *doesn't* point back to any earlier commit.  Git knows, upon reaching that commit, to stop going backwards.

**So, Git works *backwards*.  But what about making a *new* commit?**  That's actually pretty straightforward too.  Before we make our new commit, though, let's make one new *branch name*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

Git requires that we pick out *one* branch name to be the *current branch*.  We do this with `git checkout` or `git switch`.  To remember which one we picked, we'll draw in the special name `HEAD`, in parentheses, *attached to* one of these branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

Here we're `on branch main`, as `git status` will say, and using commit `H`.  If we `git checkout develop`, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

Now we're `on branch develop`, as `git status` will say, but still *using commit `H`*.  Note that **every commit is on both branches** at this point.

We now modify some files in our working tree, in the usual way (they're ordinary files that aren't actually *in* Git) and then run `git add` to prepare them for committing.  Skimming over some other fairly important stuff, this *replaces the copies of the files in Git's staging area*.  These extra copies are what Git uses to make the new commit, and the staging area actually has copies of the same files Git copied *out* of commit `H`.  They're just in ready-to-commit, compressed and pre-de-duplicated form at this point.  Using `git add` tells Git to replace some of these files with new copies: Git will compress and de-duplicate the files at `git add` time, so that `git commit` can just use whatever is in Git's index *right then*.

Finally, we run `git commit`.  This:

- Obtains metadata from us: a log message to put in the new commit, the setting of `user.name` and `user.email` right now, and so on.  The date and time stamps are "now" and the *parent* commit, for the new commit, is the *current* commit, as found by the current branch name.  So that's commit `H`, in this case.
- Makes a permanent snapshot from whatever is in Git's index right now.  Since we used `git add` to update these files, that's the right snapshot.
- Writes all of this out as a new commit.  This obtains a new, unique hash ID for the new, unique commit.  The commit object goes into the big database:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H
              \
               I
  ```

  Note how new `I` points back to existing commit `H`.  (I can't draw great arrows here, so I've gone to lines.  `H` can't point to `I` though: `H` was made long ago, and can't be changed.  So `I` must point back to `H`.)
- Last, Git does its special trick: it writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.

This last trick is what get us:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This lets us add new commits, one at a time, with each one single new commit advancing the *current branch* (`develop`, since that's where `HEAD` is attached).  If we add one more commit, we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If all looks great here, we can now simply `git checkout main` and tell Git: *commit `J` is great, use it as the last commit in `main` too*.  Skipping over the details—Git does this with what it calls a *fast-forward merge*—the result is:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

and now all commits are on both branches and it's safe to delete either name—the other one will find all commits.

Note that, earlier, it's safe (in some sense) to delete the name `main`.  We can find all the commits by starting at `J` and working backwards.  That's the point of branch names: they give us places to start from, to work backwards.  The *only* reason to *keep* `main` is to remember `H` specially for a while, but that's a fairly decent reason—especially if we decide that `I-J` are *terrible* commits after all and want to throw them out.

#### Throwing out old commits

Suppose we *do* decide that `I-J` are terrible.  Here's one way to throw them away, instead of merging them in:

```
git checkout main
git branch -D develop
```

The first step, which we'd also do if we wanted to do the fast-forward merge, gets us:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

If we run `git log` now, we don't *see* commits `I-J`.  We have to run `git log develop` to *see* them, using the name `develop` to find `J`.

The *second* command tells Git to *delete the name `develop`*—forcibly, because without forcing Git, it will say no: this would lose us access to commits `I-J`.  By deleting the name `develop`, we end up with:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

By deleting the *name*, we can't *find the commits any more* and we will never be bothered with them again—as long as we didn't *send* them to any *other* Git yet, that is.

We can now create `develop` again, pointing to `H` again, and try our development work again, this time knowing what we did wrong:

```
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

When we incorporate the (new, good) commits, we could just call them `I-J` if we like, as if the abandoned commits are totally gone.  Their real names are some big ugly hash IDs; we're just making these one-letter names up, after all.

That's all great if we're the only one doing any work, but that's not realistic in a lot of cases.

#### Parallel development

Let's start with two users.  I'll use the standard "Alice and Bob" here, although apparently this idiom is falling out of favor for some reason.  Each person makes their own clone, so that each person has their own branch names.  This gets into a small side discussion:

- Each repository *shares* commits.
- But each repository has *its own* **branch** names.

On Alice's system, she gets:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and on Bob's, he gets:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

When Alice makes two new commits (on `main` or any other branch name), her commits get *unique* hash IDs:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H
```

Meanwhile, when Bob makes two new commits, his commits also get unique hash IDs:

```
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

If we take all these commits and combine them in a single repository, and use the names `alice` and `bob` to find the last ones, we get this picture:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

(with, perhaps, `main` pointing to `H`—though we don't *need* a name for `H`, as we can find it by starting at either branch tip and working backwards).

Given the existence of parallel development, we now have a problem: *How do we join these parallel lines of development?*

#### Merge (true merges)

One way to do this is to use Git's ability to merge work.  We obtain all the commits, into some Git repository somewhere, and use branch names like the above to find them.  Then we pick one of the two branches to check out / switch to, and run `git merge` with the other:

```
git checkout alice
git merge bob
```

for instance.

Git's merge engine now does what I like to call *merge as a verb:* the action of finding *changes since some common starting point*.  The common starting point is obvious from the drawing: it's commit `H`.

Git will now use its comparison software—`git diff`, more or less—to *compare* the snapshot in commit `H` to that in commit `J`, to see what files Alice changed, and what changes Alice made to those files.  Git will also use `git diff` to compare `H` vs `L`, to see what Bob changed.  Then, for each file:

- If nobody changed the file, we just take the original file.
- If one person changed the file and the other didn't, we take the *changed* file.
- If *both* persons changed the *same* file, we have Git work hard to *combine* their changes.

Git's combining is done with a simple and stupid algorithm, that just looks at line-by-line changes.  If the changed lines don't "touch" or "overlap", Git will take *both* changes.  If they do touch-or-overlap, Git will generally declare a *merge conflict* and force the human running `git merge` to clean up the mess.  There are many special cases here, but if Alice and Bob are working on different parts of the system, Git will often be able to do all the work-combining on its own.

Since we're not really covering `git merge` properly here, let's just assume that Git thinks all went well, so that Git makes its own new commit for you.  Git applies the *combined* changes to the snapshot from the *common starting point*—what Git calls the *merge base*—in commit `H`, which keeps both sets of changes.  Git writes all of the resulting files to both your working tree and Git's own index / staging-area.  Then, Git makes a new commit from these files:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- alice (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- bob
```

Since we ran `git checkout alice` to start this, we're on branch `alice`, so the new merge commit's hash ID goes into the name `alice`.  The resulting commit has a snapshot—just like any commit—made by applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot from `H`.  It has metadata, just like any ordinary commit, saying that we made this commit just now.  The only thing special about this commit is that, instead of pointing back to *just* commit `I`, it points back to *both* branch-tip commits, `I` and `K`.

We are now allowed to delete any name we don't need.  The name we don't need here is `bob`: we can find commit `K` by working backwards through `M`.  Git will work backwards to *both* commits, following both backwards-pointing arrows automatically.

This is a true merge, and is one way to combine work.  Git can do this; GitHub can do this; and a GitHub pull request can be handled through this kind of process, as long as there are no merge conflicts.  But some *humans* don't *like* to do this.

#### Rebasing instead of merging

Let's suppose that we are Alice, and we have this situation:

```
          I--J   <-- alice (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

But Bob gets *his* commits added to some repository first:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
```

We can now run `git fetch` against this other repository—we'll call it `origin` here—to pick up new commits `K-L`.  Here is what we will see in our own local repository:

```
          I--J   <-- alice (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
```

If we have a "no merges" rule—who knows why we have this rule<sup>4</sup>—we have to take our perfectly good `I-J` commits and "improve" them, by making new commits that *add on* to `L`.

To do this manually, we'd use `git cherry-pick` twice, with a new temporary branch name, then (e.g.) change the branch names.  But the `git rebase` command can do this for us all in one go:

```
git rebase origin/main
```

The rebase operation *copies the effects* of some set of commits.  To do this, it has to use Git's merge machinery, the merge-as-a-verb part of the idea.  The `git cherry-pick` command implements this, one commit at a time, and `git merge` runs `git cherry-pick` repeatedly.<sup>5</sup>  Once it has the right *snapshot* prepared, each cherry-pick step commits this snapshot, re-using the original commit's log message, but as a regular single-parent commit, not as a merge commit.  So once this stage is done, we have:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
              \
               I'-J'  <-- HEAD
```

where `I'` is Git's automated copy of commit `I`, and `J'` is Git's automated copy of commit `J`.  This drawing also illustrates a trick that rebase uses internally: it runs in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode, to avoid having to make up a temporary branch name.<sup>6</sup>

Once all the copies are done, though, Git uses another internal command to force the original branch name to point to the last copied commit.  It then re-attaches `HEAD`, so that we have:

```
          I--J   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/main
              \
               I'-J'  <-- alice (HEAD)
```

Note how this resembles what happens when we deliberately throw out never-sent-to-anyone-else commits.

(An unfortunate side effect here is that usually, with this kind of work-flow, we've already *sent* these commits somewhere for review.  We'll touch on this in the next section.)

---

<sup>4</sup>This is, in my opinion, not really a good rule.  I've followed it before in projects—it's not a *terrible* rule—but just blindly saying "no merges" is, I think, wrong.  Still, people like it.

<sup>5</sup>In fact, `git rebase` is a horrifically complicated command, that can do its job in one of many different ways.  In modern Git, it now defaults to using `git cherry-pick` internally.  In slightly older Git versions, you need `-m` or `-i` or similar options to get it to use `git cherry-pick`.  Other options add special features, and rebase already has numerous special features so some options *disable* these features.  But mostly, it's about copying some set of existing not-quite-good-enough commits to new-and-improved commits, and that's what `git cherry-pick` is also about, so they're closely related.

<sup>6</sup>This detached HEAD mode implementation detail "leaks out" if the rebase has to stop to get help with a merge conflict, or if you use the `git rebase -i` variant and make it stop on purpose: when rebase stops in the middle of the operation, you're still in this detached-HEAD mode.  You must tell Git to resume the rebase, or terminate it, to get out of the detached-HEAD mode.  This gets messy, and you should be careful not to use `git checkout` to get out of the detached HEAD mode.

---

#### Rebasing in the GitHub fork world

All of the above is stuff we can do in base Git.  GitHub and other hosting sites, however, add on a bunch of features, in the hope that we'll like those features enough to actually *pay* for services on those hosting sites.

The first GitHub specific feature is the GitHub fork.  A fork, on GitHub, is like a clone, but with two changes:

- Normally, if we use `git clone` to clone a repository:

  ```
  git clone -b foo ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
  ```

  we get all of the *commits* from that repository, and none of their *branches*.  Our `git clone` ends by creating, locally, *one* branch name, using the name we gave to the `-b` argument here.  If we did not give a `-b` argument, our Git asks their (GitHub's) Git what branch name they recommend, and our Git then creates that one branch based on their recommendation.

  What our Git does with their *branch* names is to change them all to *remote-tracking names:* their `main` becomes our `origin/main`, their `develop` becomes our `origin/develop`, their `feature/short` becomes our `origin/feature/short`, and so on.

  Git does this because our branch names are *ours*, to do with as we will.  It would be OK for Git to copy *all* the `origin/*` names back, but one way or another, Git still needs this kind of "rename their branches, and use our own names" trick so that we don't lose *our* **new** commits when we get updates from *their* Git.

  With a GitHub fork, though, our Git creates one branch name in our fork for each branch name that was in the original Git.  That's harmless and in some ways nice (see previous paragraph).
- And, behind the scenes, GitHub *shares* the underlying commits and other internal objects, so as to save space on their own servers—this is always OK because each object gets its own unique hash ID—*and* remembers *their* repository for us, so that we can make Pull Requests.

This ability to make pull requests is one of the big selling features.  (GitHub's ability to manage review comments, issues, and so on is another.  That, too, is an add-on, not present in base Git.)

A pull request is at its heart just a way that we can send email or some other alert to the owner of the repository we used when we clicked on the <kbd>FORK</kbd> button, to let them know that, in our GitHub fork, we've added some commit(s) that we are now offering to them to look at and/or add to *their* clone.  It's up to them whether they take our commits as-is—this requires that they use raw Git, or the GitHub <kbd>MERGE</kbd> button—or make some sort of changes to them, or ask us to make changes to them, or whatever.

If they *do* ask us to make changes to our commit(s), *we* can do that and then use `git push --force` to send our *new* commits to our own GitHub fork.

I mentioned earlier that Git "does not like" to give up commits.  When we use `git rebase` *or any other process* to replace existing commits with new-and-improved replacements, if we've ever sent the *originals* anywhere and we now send the replacements, we're going to be asking that other Git repository to *give up* the originals, taking the replacements instead.

When we *did* the replacing, our Git knew we were doing that, if we used `git rebase` at least.  (If we did it manually, we probably had to *force* our Git to take our replacements.)  The Git over at GitHub has no idea that our new-and-improved replacement commits are the result of `git rebase`, so we have to force the Git at GitHub to take them *as* replacements.  So we have to `git push --force` to our fork.

The add-on software that GitHub use will notice this forced-push to the branch that we used when we made the Pull Request, and will *automatically update the PR* that the other folks see, when they look at our PR.

This doesn't tell us *why* we have to rebase.  It can't, because Git itself, and GitHub as an add-on, doesn't *require* rebasing in the first place.  It's some humans somewhere that made this requirement.  Since so many humans *like* this process (for whatever reason), GitHub might even automate that requirement today or tomorrow.

In any case, if you made it this far, you now know *how* to do it and that it's not required by any of the underlying software.  But there's one more thing to consider.

#### Merges that can't be automated cannot be done on GitHub

(This is actually an overstatement, because GitHub have been adding new features.  But generally it *was* true, and it affects both merge and rebase.)

When Git can combine changes on its own, it will do so, and GitHub's use of Git will do so as well.  When Git *can't* combine changes on its own, it needs to get help from someone.

If a merge has merge conflicts, Git will stop and leave a mess in your working tree.  It is now your job to fix the mess.  Git repositories *on* GitHub *do not have working trees* (for various internal reasons), so there's nowhere to fix the mess.

Hence, before GitHub will let you make a Pull Request, they first run a *test merge*.  This test merge either succeeds, because Git can do everything on its own, or fails, because it can't.  If the test merge fails, GitHub will let you know that your PR has conflicts.

Now, suppose you have a fork, and a local copy of the repository on your laptop, and you do some work and make some commits and they're all ready to go:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

You send this to your GitHub fork, so that your GitHub clone has an `alice` branch with commit `J` as its last commit.  The repository you forked still has commit `H` as its last commit on *their* `main` too, and you make your PR.

Along comes our annoying fellow Bob, who makes some commits:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- bob
```

Bob gets these commmits added to their `main`, and they have not yet picked up your work:

```
          I--J   <-- alice
         /
...--G--H--K--L   <-- main
```

There was no conflict between your work (extending their commit `H`) before, but *now there is* because Bob touched the *same lines* of the *same files* and made incompatible changes.

The GitHub system can no longer combine your work in `I-J` with their branch tip `L`.  Your PR has become *conflicted*, in GitHub's terms.  They (GitHub) noticed this when they added commits `K-L` to their (GitHub's other-persons-clone's, from which you forked) `main`.

GitHub will let you know, so that you can either retract your PR entirely, or do something about the merge conflict.  *You don't have to rebase your PR* due to base Git requirements.  You *do* have to solve the merge conflict due to base Git requirements, perhaps by adding a new commit that comes after `J` that can merge well with `L`.  GitHub add-ons may change this picture, but the conflict itself causes the need to update the PR.  The required update isn't *necessarily* a rebase.

Comment: I have taken it upon myself to go through some of your answers to better understand git. I have a question on `All parts of any commit, once created, are read-only. ` Given this, `github` provides a choice if you click on the three dots to the top right of a directory to delete the directory. Could you please clarify how this fits in with the notion of each commit being read only? Perhaps you have answered that in your long post. I am going part by part, hence the query at this stage.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this GitHub interface you mention, but if they take some existing commit out and modify it, they must put the result back as a new, different commit. That's generally how new commits come about: we extract some existing commit, fiddle with the working-tree copies of files (maybe even creating new files or deleting files entirely), then instruct Git to store the results as a new commit.

Comment: (I'll also note here that when I look at one of my GitHub repositories right now, I don't have three dots to the top right of a directory. That may be because I don't bother "signing in"—I work on these things locally, in a clone...)